# Meteor wrapAsync or bindEnvironment without standard callback signature

Tags: meteor, node-fibers

I'm trying to call `createTableIfNotExists` in this npm package, and do so synchronously in Meteor, server-side.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage

However, the callback signature is of type `function(error, result, response)` instead of the traditional `function(error,result)`.

1) Because of that, I cannot use `Meteor.wrapAsync` and instead have to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment`

2) I call 'bindEnvironment' as below. Note the callback with 3 arguments. This works, but now I would like to extract the `return value`, back to the original method (i.e. the original fiber).

Note that simply defining 'addResult' outside the `createTableService` does not work because the callback inside `bindEnvironment` runs asynchrounously relative to the outside code...i.e. `demoFunction()` returns before the callback sets `addResult`.

```
var demoFunction = function(){
    var addResult = null;
    var tableService = azure.createTableService(acctName, acctKey);
                    tableService.createTableIfNotExists(asTableName, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error,result,response){
                        if (error) {
                            throw new Meteor.Error(500, "table create error - " + asTableName + ": "+ error);
                        }
                        console.log(result);
                        if(result){
                            addResult = /*call to meteor method*/ 
                            return addResult;
                        }                   
                    }));

    return addResult; //this is what I would like to do, but will always be null, as written.

}
```

How can I call `createTableIfNotExists` and still return `addResult` ***back to the function that called*** `demoFunction()`?

Thanks!

Comment: Using `future` should work. I

Comment: thanks - could you please elaborate? I am not familiar at all with ` future` . Looking at this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers but can't figure out how to rework my code above.
====OR====
Is returning a Promise from `demoFunction()` an option as well? I am more familiar with using `async/await`

Comment: Sorry for the short answer I am on the run and will try to give you a more detailed answer when I am at home.

Comment: Actually, returning a Promise from `demoFunction`, and then `rejecting/resolving` it inside the bindEnvironment function worked...I did not realize `bindEnvironment` would resolve the outer Promise....although now it makes sense that it carries over the external environment given its name :) =====>>>>> If possible, I'd still like to see a `Future` solution that might enable arbitrary # of asynchrnous calls by creating synchronicity with the `demoFunction()` fiber, as I will probably need it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Future` from the `fibers/future` ([node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers)) package, which is just a different abstraction layer of fibers as [this async/await implementation](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait) or [this promise implementation](https://github.com/lm1/node-fibers-promise) are,
 too. (Note, that using a fiber directly [is not recommended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers#examples)).

## Generic Future pattern

As you already pointed out, you can solve this issue also using async/await or using promises.

However, if you want to know how to use a `Future` instance, you can follow [this popular pattern](https://www.discovermeteor.com/patterns/5828399), which I make use of in many of my applications.

## Future pattern with Meteor.bindEnvironment

Including the `bindEnvironment` into this pattern, and restructuring the code a bit, it looks like the following:

```js
import Future from 'fibers/future';

Meteor.methods({
    myMeteorMethod: function() {
        // load Future
        const myFuture = new Future();

        // create bound callback, that uses the future
        const boundCallback = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (error,results){
            if(error){
              myFuture.throw(error);
            }else{
              myFuture.return(results);
            }
        });

        // call the function and pass bound callback
        SomeAsynchronousFunction("foo", boundCallback);

        return myFuture.wait();
    }
});
```

## Applied to code example

Applying this modification of the pattern to your code, it could result in something like the code below. 
Note, that I separated the callback from being created inside the function simply because of readability. You can of course just create it inside the function head, as you typically do.

```js
import Future from 'fibers/future';

var demoFunction = function(){
    // load Future
    const myFuture = new Future();

    // create bound callback, that uses the future
    const boundCallback = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (error, result, response) {
        if (error) {
            myFuture.throw(new Meteor.Error(500, "table create error - " + asTableName + ": "+ error));
        }

        // do whatever you need to do here
        // with result and response...

        if (result) {
            myFuture.return(result);
        }                   
    });

    var tableService = azure.createTableService(acctName, acctKey);

    // pass the bound callback here
    tableService.createTableIfNotExists(asTableName, boundCallback);

    return myFuture.wait();

}
```