# Meteor Incrementing Some Values in DB each second

Tags: meteor

I am developing a simple farming game backend using meteor.

So Server needs to check all players farm data and based on that for example increment

```
production:0
```

field each second if player has a farm.
What is the best way to do that ?

Should i use `Meteor.setTimeout()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Meteor.setTimeout](https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html#Meteor-setTimeout) if you don't manually want to bind fibers to the callback function.

Related issues:

[What's going on with Meteor and Fibers/bindEnvironment()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994951/whats-going-on-with-meteor-and-fibers-bindenvironment)

[Meteor wrapAsync or bindEnvironment without standard callback signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391067/meteor-wrapasync-or-bindenvironment-without-standard-callback-signature)

However, you can also use the native JS setTimeout but you will have to manually bind a fiber to the callback (if you aim to use for example Mongo) using [Meteor.bindEnvironment](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#bind-environment) or [Meteor.wrapAsync](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync).

Another interesting tool is [Meteor.defer](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-defer) which is similar to `Meteor.setTimeout(func, 0)` and allows to execute code in the background. Beware of several layers of callbacks when mixing with `Meteor.setTimeout`.

Ans yet another tool when executing complex services in a method is [this.unblock](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-unblock).

Applying these tools in an appropriate way will make your timer based update possible.